# overwrite c++20 spaceship operator for enum class

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm struggling with providing the new spaceship-operator for a enum class. Lets take the following example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>
#include <cstdint>

enum class Animals : uint8_t
{
  Bird = 27, //those values are just for making a point
  Tiger = 5,
  Ant = 100,
  Snake = 45,
  Wale = 17
};

//auto operator<=(const Animals& lhs, const Animals& rhs) = delete;
//auto operator>=(const Animals& lhs, const Animals& rhs) = delete;
//auto operator<(const Animals& lhs, const Animals& rhs) = delete;
//auto operator>(const Animals& lhs, const Animals& rhs) = delete;

auto operator<=>(const Animals& lhs, const Animals& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "comparing via overloaded <=> operator\n";
  //order the animals by their size in real life
  // Ant < Bird < Snake < Tiger < Wale
  //for this MVCE only Ant < Tiger is in here:
  if(lhs == Animals::Ant && rhs == Animals::Tiger)
    return -1;
  return 0; //all unimplemented ones are treated as equal
}

int main(void)
{
  if(Animals::Ant < Animals::Tiger)
    std::puts("success (do I see the prompt of the overloaded operator?)");
  else
    std::puts("seems to use uint8_t comparison instead");

  return 0;
  
}
```

But obviously I'm getting something wrong in here, as my `main()` still tells me, that Ants are bigger than Tigers. As you can see I tried to explicitly delete the default comparison-operators, to force the compiler to use my custom-spaceship-one, but without success.

When I explicit call `auto result = Animals::Ant <=> Animals::Tiger` I get an `ambiguous overload for 'operator<=>' (operand types are 'Animals' and 'Animals')`. But that seems to be related to my operators signature (using `const` Animals instead).

Is it possible to overwrite the operator for my Enum (without interfering with the operators for its basic type "uint8_t"?

Comment: Your op returns a raw `int`. The return type must be a [comparison category](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/compare.syn#header:%3ccompare%3e) for the plumbing to work, I believe.

Comment: Indeed, and it should also accept pointer and enumeration types by value: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison (the paragraph right above example for three-way comparison). Note that gcc and clang seem to disagree on the results, that sounds like a bug in one of the compilers (no idea which one is right tho): https://godbolt.org/z/vKsPG9x1q

Comment: The operator should return one of ordering categories instead of auto int, maybe `std::weak_ordering`

Comment: cppreference says enum need to take by value. and take by value do solve the problem (no need to return special ordering)

Comment: It seems the spaceship operator for enums only works for clang 11+, icc-2021 and msvc-19.29.  But not on any version of gcc.  Even after changing return type to int and passing by value.  https://godbolt.org/z/x6PjWdesT

Comment: (continue my comment) but the reference version does result in ambiguous  https://godbolt.org/z/qeh6nzWME (i.e. it's indeed considered by compiler). not sure what's going on (not sure why it should take by value either).

Comment: also ambiguous in msvc https://godbolt.org/z/xYYsnjvd6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your `operator<=>`:

1. it needs to take the enums by value, not by reference-to-const, in order to the suppress the built-in candidate
2. it needs to return one of the comparison categories, not `int`. In this case probably `std::weak_ordering` is right.

That is:

```cpp
constexpr auto operator<=>(Animals lhs, Animals rhs) -> std::weak_ordering
{
  //order the animals by their size in real life
  // Ant < Bird < Snake < Tiger < Wale
  //for this MVCE only Ant < Tiger is in here:
  if(lhs == Animals::Ant && rhs == Animals::Tiger)
    return std::weak_ordering::less;
  return std::weak_ordering::equivalent;
}
```

That said, there is implementation divergence for how to handle rewrite candidates with `<=>`. clang and msvc implement what the rules probably should be, which is that our user-declared `operator<=>` suppresses *all* the built-in relational and three-way comaprison operators, so that `Animals::Ant < Animals::Tiger` invokes our `operator<=>`. But gcc implements what the rules technically actually literally say, which is that `Animals::Ant <=> Animals::Tiger` evaluates our operator but using `<` does not. There is a gcc bug report open for this ([#105200](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105200)), where one of the gcc developers points out the wording issue. This strikes me as a wording issue, rather than an actual design intent issue, so I'm opening a Core issue about this ([#205](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/205)).

In order for this to work on gcc, you have to also go through and add these yourself (note: always by value):

```cpp
constexpr auto operator<(Animals lhs, Animals rhs) -> bool {
    return (lhs <=> rhs) < 0;
}

constexpr auto operator<=(Animals lhs, Animals rhs) -> bool {
    return (lhs <=> rhs) <= 0;
}

constexpr auto operator>(Animals lhs, Animals rhs) -> bool {
    return (lhs <=> rhs) > 0;
}

constexpr auto operator>=(Animals lhs, Animals rhs) -> bool {
    return (lhs <=> rhs) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. But why was my `const&` wrong? According to the top table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) the signature of the operator as a freestanding-function should be: `/*R*/ operator <=>(const T &a, const T2 &b);`

Comment: okay I think @Yksisarvinen answered it in the comment under my question. For enums it should be `operator<=>(T a, T b)`